# Adding all numbers from string

Tags: c++

I'm trying to add all numbers from string, but I can't figure out how do I add a 2 digit number.
ex: ab32d3
I want the answer to be 35.
This is my code:

```
int main()
{
int max=0,min=100000,sum=0,totalsum=0;
string s;
ifstream in ("Unos.txt");

while(getline(in,s))
{
    cout<<s<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();++i)
    {
        if(s[i]>max)
        {
            max=s[i]-'0';
        }
        if(s[i]<min)
        {
            min=s[i]-'0';
        }
        if(isdigit(s[i]))
        {
            sum=10*sum+s[i]-'0';
        }
        else
        {
            totalsum+=sum;
            sum=0;
        }
    }
}
totalsum+=sum;
cout<<"Najveci broj je: "<<max<<endl;
cout<<"Najmanji broj je: "<<min<<endl;
cout<<"Zbir svih brojeva je: "<<totalsum<<endl;
return 0;
```

}

Comment: From `ab32d3` how is 35 arrived at. Also better that using 48 would be `'0'`

Comment: I mean not to add digits but if there are 2 digits right one after another to think of it as a 2 digit number instead of 3 + 2 + 3 I need it to do 32+3 and thanks for the '0'

Comment: and can you explain why is using '0' better and what does it do?

Comment: Because it makes it more obvious that you are taking away the ASCII value for `'0'` rather than having to scratch ones head and remember that it has a value of 48

Comment: @Tibor 
You can try catching substrings with RegEx like `/\d+/g`, then converting them to int with `std::stoi`. 
_remember to make sure if they are indeed the numbers_
[example](http://regexr.com/3d49l)

Comment: std::stoi doesn't work with my compiler I've tried that on asigment that I did before.

Comment: How about `atoi(str.c_str())` ? _str_ is Your string of course

Comment: That doesn't work either tried that.

Comment: How do you implement a regular expression to a code?

Comment: which compiler are you using?

Comment: did you include <cstdlib> for atoi ?

Comment: But I can't figure out how do I implement RegEx into my code

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the poster is trying to keep modifying the question. (and this is for a competition)

Comment: You have not explained what problem you are facing, what result you are getting that is unexpected, and what steps you have taken already to discover the source of the problem.

Comment: @EdHeal I was practising for the competiton and there was no task like this on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   string str = "ab32d3", temp;
   int sum = 0;

   for ( int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++ ) {
       if ( isdigit(str[i]) ) temp.push_back(str[i]);
       else {
           if ( temp.size() > 0 ) {
               sum += stoi(temp);
               temp = string();
           }   
       }
   }

   // Last number (if exists)
   if ( temp.size() > 0 ) sum += stoi(temp);

   cout << sum << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

It will print `35`

Comment: It says that stoi is not declared

Comment: Did you include string header? `#include <string>`

Comment: Okay, then you compiler doesn't support `c++11`. Change `stoi(temp)` to `atoi(temp.c_str())`

Comment: @Tibor Include `<cstdlib>` and try again

Comment: Now it says that range based 'for' loops are not allowed in C++ 98 mode

Comment: @Tibor Okay, let me change it

Comment: @Tibor Now it should be okay

Comment: Why are you using `stoi` when it is simple to keep the running total and avoid that overhead?

Comment: @EdHeal It's just a solution, not the best one. I just gave OP something to start with.

Comment: @DimChtz - It is not a perfect answer but you get a +1 for patience with Tibor

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

int main() {

    std::string s = "ab32d3";
    int value_so_far = 0;
    int total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
    {
        if (isdigit(s[i])) { // This keeps a running total until the number ends
            value_so_far = 10 * value_so_far + s[i] - '0';
        } else { // Here the number has ended - Add to the total and reset
            total += value_so_far;
            value_so_far = 0;
        }
    }

    // Got to the end - Add what is left!
    total += value_so_far;

    std::cout << "Ans:" << total << std::endl;
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the link: [ideone code](https://ideone.com/qlcuNV).

Please check the comments in the code as to the explanation.

Comment: This works, but now that I try to read from a text file that has text written in two lines it gives me a lot bigger value

Comment: @Tibor - You have moved the goal post. Read the file line by line. Use this as a function template.

Comment: Minimum and maximum value work for multiple lines but this doesn't

Comment: @tibor - In your code you have not even declared `max` and `min`

Comment: Actually it doesn't work only when first character of 2nd line is a number

Comment: I do, but it didn't copy

Comment: My code works perfectly for a string. Read each line in turn as a string `getline` perhaps. So why not post this additional code?

Comment: I do get my string with getline. I will try to edit my code again so could you check for an error.

Comment: *You can lead a horse to water but you cannot make it drink* - You have two valid answers - please use the material and work things out for yourself

Comment: I have a competition tomorrow, morning and its really late at night currently and I can't figure this out

Comment: So you want me to write the code for you to win this competition - do I get a prize? I guess I do not.

Comment: No, we get our tasks tomorrow, I just need help if there is this type of task to do, but thanks anyways for help

Comment: And I wouldn't cheat I'm not a person like that.